# Node running out of memory in simple loop

Tags: node.js, mongoose, garbage-collection

Trying to do some geo-spacial performance stress tests.

I have the following code 
(I cannot --expose-gc with grunt [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047831/cannot-expose-gc-with-grunt-nodemon) so i can't call global.gc()).

```
    var getRandomRange = function(start, end){
        return parseFloat((Math.random() * (start - end) + end).toFixed(4));
    }

    /* Max and min long and lat.
    Latitude : max/min +90 to -90
    Longitude : max/min +180 to -180
    */
    var createRandomSeeds = function(index)
    {
        var createSeedsTestPropertyData = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            createSeedsTestPropertyData.push({
                name:i.toString(),
                location: [
                  getRandomRange(+90, -90), getRandomRange(+180, -180)
                ]
            });
        }

        //Mongoose create records.
        Property.create(createSeedsTestPropertyData);
        console.log('Created many records, ' + index);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        createRandomSeeds(i);
    }
```

I assumed that node would deallocate the memory automatically.

Now I've been stuck in my spare time for over 2h because I cannot seed test.

Does anyone know what I can do to avoid this? (v4.2.1)

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

   31667 ms: Scavenge 1401.8 (1457.0) -> 1401.8 (1457.0) MB, 8.6 / 0 ms (+ 2.4 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
   32749 ms: Mark-sweep 1401.8 (1457.0) -> 1401.8 (1456.0) MB, 1082.0 / 0 ms (+ 3.4 ms in 2 steps since start of marking, biggest step 2.4 ms) [last resort gc].
   33867 ms: Mark-sweep 1401.8 (1456.0) -> 1401.6 (1457.0) MB, 1118.0 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the async nature of `Property.create` to allow GC to occur while your code waits for the records to be created. In its current form, your code synchronously queues up all 1M records to create.

You can do this by adding a `callback` parameter to your `createRandomSeeds` method that you call when the `Property.create` call has completed and then replace your synchronous `for` loop with one that iterates asynchronously like the [`whilst`](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst) method of the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) library.

But I'd also recommend not creating 1000 docs in a single `create` call; 100 is probably a reasonable maximum. So note that change as well in the below example:

```
var createRandomSeeds = function (index, callback) {
    var createSeedsTestPropertyData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        createSeedsTestPropertyData.push({
            name: i.toString(),
            location: [
              getRandomRange(+90, -90), getRandomRange(+180, -180)
            ]
        });
    }

    Property.create(createSeedsTestPropertyData, function(err) {
        console.log('Created many records, ' + index);
        callback(err);
    });
}

var i = 0;
async.whilst(
    // Keep looping asynchronously while i < 10000
    function () { return i < 10000; },
    function (callback) {
        i++;
        createRandomSeeds(i, callback);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('All done');
    }
);
```